# Force SSL and WWW on apache2 for raspbian

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, raspberry-pi

When I use the mod_rewrite and mod_ssl concurrently below, the resulting domain is: https://www.domain.com// I find this extra '/' annoying and I would like to get rid of it. Is the problem the way I code it or should I consider using .htaccess instead?

000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.fusioncodes\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.fusioncodes.com/$1 [R=301,L]
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile    ~server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ~server.key
 ..... More SSL Stuff
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 3rd line (`RewriteRule`) with that:

```
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.fusioncodes.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) 
`RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Agreed! I gave an answer with the updated RewriteRule (2nd Rule) which i thought may work. The WIKI link was only for reference and was not an answer.